# How to compare filter keyword with all columns in a table by EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table whose name is Table1 and the column name are Id, Name, and Description. The table structure is:

```
Table1:
Id - Name - Description 
1  - apple1 - It is sweet 
2  - apple2 - It is sour
3  - apple3 - It is sweet and sour
```

I want to filter data from Table1 using EF. If the search keyword is apple1 then I will want to compare that keyword in all columns. Like as

```
Table1.Where(x => x.Id == keyword || x.Name == keyword || x.Description == keyword)
```

Is it possible in EF Core?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it using EF. Just a little improvement, with the fields `Name` and `Description` you may want to search by the operator `Contains` instead because their type's string (you may encounter the situation with uppercase and lowercase)

```
Table1.Where(x => x.ID == keyword
               || x.Name.Contains(keyword)
               || x.Description.Contains(keyword))
```